# How to create postgresql database using Ant?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, ant

Is there any method to create postgresql database unsing ant?

I put an SQL creation statement inside a `sql` Task:

```
<sql
driver="${driver}"
url="${url}"
userid="${userid}"
password="${password}"
autocommit="true">
CREATE DATABASE ${project};
</sql>
```

there is no exception but the database is not created.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Useful thread : http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2005-11/msg00129.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must be something with your environment, the following works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="create-db" name="SOTest">
    <target name="create-db">
       <sql driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
            classpath="postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/template1"
            userid="postgres"
            password="secretpassword"
            autocommit="true">

         CREATE DATABASE sampledb;
       </sql>
    </target>

</project>
```

To which database are you connecting in your JDBC url?